# Company name when submitting iPhone app to App Store

Tags: iphone, app-store

I have an individual membership with the Apple developer program. When I submit my app to the app store, will my name show up as the seller, or will I be able to put a different name, specifically, a company name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. The Seller info is what you put under itunes connect.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, the name of the individual is what appears as the seller through an individual account. If you had a business membership, then the name of the business would appear there. That's one of the perks of the business option, aside from team management.

This may have changed in the last year since I last submitted an app, but I'm fairly confident it has not. Please feel free to correct me if it has.

Comment: I looked at a bunch of other resources, including a raywenderlich article (http://www.raywenderlich.com/8045/how-to-submit-your-app-to-apple-from-no-account-to-app-store-part-2), and it shows that you can put a company name when submitting your first application. thanks for the input, i guess i won't really know for sure until i actually submit it.